segfault in using getline() function in C
I was implementing a basic getline() function for reading content of file and writing it to terminal however 
this works completely fine
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[argc-1],"r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("error : can't open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t linelen  = 0;
    size_t linecapp = 0;
    while((linelen = getline(&buf,&linecapp,fp)) !=-1)
    {
        fwrite(buf,linelen,1,stdout);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

but this
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[argc-1],"r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("error : can't open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t linelen  = 0;
    size_t linecapp = 0;
    while((linelen = getline(&buf,&linecapp,fp)) >= 0)
    {
        fwrite(buf,linelen,1,stdout);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

is giving segmentation fault.
only thing that differ is
!= -1 and >= 0 in while loop which is the same thing.

What I tried
printf("%zu\n", linelen);
inside my while loop and I got this
<\n><\n>
116
hello world this is a test file to bes used for the purpose of learning basics of unix sys calls and c programming 
77
this is just an extra line to elongate the file followed by more extra lines
55
for example this is a line used in elongating the file
22
this is another line 
141
this line contain special characters like œ∑´®†¥¨ˆøπåß∂ƒ©˙∆˚¬¬¬…≈ç√∫˜µ≤≥÷¡™£¢∞§¶•ªº–
52
this line contain some numbers 1 2 3 5 7 4 6 8 9 10
18446744073709551615
his line contain some numbers 1 2 3 5 7 4 6 8 9 10
?¥¨ˆøπåß∂ƒ©˙∆˚¬¬¬…≈ç√∫˜µ≤≥÷¡™£¢∞§¶•ªº–
Xjm??ͫ?????@|m? ?5?r?@?@:?#??Zm@?` `@?`?`?Zm???#? ??#????#?????#?@?`X???\/var/folders/l5/h45_tftn3w18ws8vshrpxlsr0000gn/T//private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.pIOsn5DWl2/Listeners0?``SSH_AUTH_SOCK??`??????????????????`??`P ?b??,?,?8Zm@??Xm? ??`(?`?`HOME?Xm?D<?B`38?`P`PATH?Xm?81??` ?`?`TMPDIR?Xm?83?`??!???c?8???W&???ǀ?G???w+???C???????`??`@``?```?Z??`ԥ`???`???`???`?@`?a??\_?x?`?`?`?Z????^??\_?x?`????`?pm??   ??
m ??um??     ?x ?h
m?
 ?@
m?? ??
m?`
 ??
zsh: segmentation fault  ./getlinefunc ../../sampletextfile.txt

for comparison here's orignal sampletextfile
hello world this is a test file to be used for the purpose of learning basics of unix sys calls and c programming 
this is just an extra line to elongate the file followed by more extra lines
for example this is a line used in elongating the file
this is another line 
this line contain special characters like œ∑´®†¥¨ˆøπåß∂ƒ©˙∆˚¬¬¬…≈ç√∫˜µ≤≥÷¡™£¢∞§¶•ªº–
this line contain some numbers 1 2 3 5 7 4 6 8 9 10

it's taking on some very large value for linelen at the end.

what about value 0 ?
"not equal to minus one" and "larger than and also not 0" are not the same

You probably messed around with the command line arguments from case to case.

Thought of doing a printf("%zu\n", linelen); in each loop?

@Guillius seg fault for >= 0 also

@paddy it's giving a very large value at the end (which is 2^64-1) could it be it roundabout itself when reaching -ve sign because size_t is unsigned

The variable linelen is unsigned, and so it is always greater or equal to zero.
The documentation states:

On error, returns -1 and sets feof or ferror on stream.

The equality test with -1 works because the negative return value is automatically converted to its unsigned equivalent when assigned to an unsigned value, then the -1 is automatically converted to unsigned when compared to an unsigned value.
The actual issue here is that return type of getline is ssize_t which is the signed version of a size_t value. So you should be using the appropriate type instead, then both versions of your loop will work:
char *buf = NULL;
ssize_t linelen  = 0;
size_t linecapp = 0;
while((linelen = getline(&buf,&linecapp,fp)) >= 0)
{
    fwrite(buf,linelen,1,stdout);
}
free(buf);


The example in the man page on my system uses > 0. This may be preferable although I don't see any way that 0 could be returned since the new-line is included as part of the output.
